# d3.js Pie Chart With label

Tags: d3.js, charts

I started working with this d3.js Donut Chart:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thudfactor/HdwTH/)I am trying to change it into a Pie Chart without the circle in the middle.  I am new to d3.js.  I have tried several different ideas but have been unable to get this to remove the circle in the middle of the chart.  Any and all help is appreciated

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .label-text {
            alignment-baseline : middle;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family: arial,helvetica,"sans-serif";
            fill: #393939;
        }
        .label-line {
            stroke-width: 1;
            stroke: #393939;
        }
        .label-circle {
            fill: #393939;
        }
    </style>
     <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg>
        <g id="canvas">
            <g id="art" />
            <g id="labels" /></g>
    </svg>
    <script>
        var data = [{
            label: 'Star Wars',
            instances: 207
        }, {
            label: 'Lost In Space',
            instances: 3
        }, {
            label: 'the Boston Pops',
            instances: 20
        }, {
            label: 'Indiana Jones',
            instances: 150
        }, {
            label: 'Harry Potter',
            instances: 75
        }, {
            label: 'Jaws',
            instances: 5
        }, {
            label: 'Lincoln',
            instances: 1
        }];

        svg = d3.select("svg");
        canvas = d3.select("#canvas");
        art = d3.select("#art");
        labels = d3.select("#labels");

        // Create the pie layout function.
        // This function will add convenience
        // data to our existing data, like 
        // the start angle and end angle
        // for each data element.
        jhw_pie = d3.layout.pie();
        jhw_pie.sort(null);
        jhw_pie.value(function (d) {
            // Tells the layout function what
            // property of our data object to
            // use as the value.
            return d.instances;
        });

        // Store our chart dimensions
        cDim = {
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            innerRadius: 50,
            outerRadius: 150,
            labelRadius: 175
        }

        // Set the size of our SVG element
        svg.attr({
            height: cDim.height,
            width: cDim.width
        });

        // This translate property moves the origin of the group's coordinate
        // space to the center of the SVG element, saving us translating every
        // coordinate individually. 
        canvas.attr("transform", "translate(" + (cDim.width / 2) + "," + (cDim.height / 2) + ")");

        pied_data = jhw_pie(data);

        // The pied_arc function we make here will calculate the path
        // information for each wedge based on the data set. This is 
        // used in the "d" attribute.
        pied_arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(50)
            .outerRadius(150);

        // This is an ordinal scale that returns 10 predefined colors.
        // It is part of d3 core.
        pied_colors = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .range(["#04B486", "#F2F2F2", "#F5F6CE", "#00BFFF","orange","purple","pink"]);

        // Let's start drawing the arcs.
        enteringArcs = art.selectAll(".wedge").data(pied_data)
            .enter();

        enteringArcs
         .append("g")
            .attr("class", "wedge")
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", pied_arc)
            .style("fill", function (d, i) {
                return pied_colors(i);
            });

        // Now we'll draw our label lines, etc.
        enteringLabels = labels.selectAll(".label").data(pied_data).enter();
        labelGroups = enteringLabels.append("g").attr("class", "label");
        labelGroups.append("circle").attr({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            r: 2,
            fill: "#000",
            transform: function (d, i) {
                centroid = pied_arc.centroid(d);
                return "translate(" + pied_arc.centroid(d) + ")";
            },
            'class': "label-circle"
        });

        // "When am I ever going to use this?" I said in 
        // 10th grade trig.
        textLines = labelGroups.append("line").attr({
            x1: function (d, i) {
                return pied_arc.centroid(d)[0];
            },
            y1: function (d, i) {
                return pied_arc.centroid(d)[1];
            },
            x2: function (d, i) {
                centroid = pied_arc.centroid(d);
                midAngle = Math.atan2(centroid[1], centroid[0]);
                x = Math.cos(midAngle) * cDim.labelRadius;
                return x;
            },
            y2: function (d, i) {
                centroid = pied_arc.centroid(d);
                midAngle = Math.atan2(centroid[1], centroid[0]);
                y = Math.sin(midAngle) * cDim.labelRadius;
                return y;
            },
            'class': "label-line"
        });

        textLabels = labelGroups.append("text").attr({
            x: function (d, i) {
                centroid = pied_arc.centroid(d);
                midAngle = Math.atan2(centroid[1], centroid[0]);
                x = Math.cos(midAngle) * cDim.labelRadius;
                sign = (x > 0) ? 1 : -1
                labelX = x + (5 * sign)
                return labelX;
            },
            y: function (d, i) {
                centroid = pied_arc.centroid(d);
                midAngle = Math.atan2(centroid[1], centroid[0]);
                y = Math.sin(midAngle) * cDim.labelRadius;
                return y;
            },
            'text-anchor': function (d, i) {
                centroid = pied_arc.centroid(d);
                midAngle = Math.atan2(centroid[1], centroid[0]);
                x = Math.cos(midAngle) * cDim.labelRadius;
                return (x > 0) ? "start" : "end";
            },
            'class': 'label-text'
        }).text(function (d) {
            return d.data.label
        });

        alpha = 0.5;
        spacing = 12;

        function relax() {
            again = false;
            textLabels.each(function (d, i) {
                a = this;
                da = d3.select(a);
                y1 = da.attr("y");
                textLabels.each(function (d, j) {
                    b = this;
                    // a & b are the same element and don't collide.
                    if (a == b) return;
                    db = d3.select(b);
                    // a & b are on opposite sides of the chart and
                    // don't collide
                    if (da.attr("text-anchor") != db.attr("text-anchor")) return;
                    // Now let's calculate the distance between
                    // these elements. 
                    y2 = db.attr("y");
                    deltaY = y1 - y2;

                    // Our spacing is greater than our specified spacing,
                    // so they don't collide.
                    if (Math.abs(deltaY) > spacing) return;

                    // If the labels collide, we'll push each 
                    // of the two labels up and down a little bit.
                    again = true;
                    sign = deltaY > 0 ? 1 : -1;
                    adjust = sign * alpha;
                    da.attr("y", +y1 + adjust);
                    db.attr("y", +y2 - adjust);
                });
            });
            // Adjust our line leaders here
            // so that they follow the labels. 
            if (again) {
                labelElements = textLabels[0];
                textLines.attr("y2", function (d, i) {
                    labelForLine = d3.select(labelElements[i]);
                    return labelForLine.attr("y");
                });
                setTimeout(relax, 20)
            }
        }

        relax();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HdwTH/226/).

The code contained the following lines, of which the `innerRadious` was changed to 0.

```
pied_arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(00) // <- this
    .outerRadius(150);
```

It's a bit misleading, as there's an `innerRadius` variable somewhere before that, but it's not used at this point. While you're at it, you might want to align all of that stuff.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept - I actually think it solves the problem completely.